# Oracle Update Statement Based on Select Query w/ Joins Not Working

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I'm trying to apply an update query based on a select query that has joins, but it's not working.

```
UPDATE (
  SELECT 
    LOCATION_NUM, LOCATION_TYPE, LOCATION_CITY, ACCOUNT_NUM
  FROM 
    TBLSALES T1
    INNER JOIN TBLCENTER  T2 ON T2.LOCATION_ID = T1.LOCATION_ID
    INNER JOIN TBLACCOUNT T3 ON T3.ACCOUNT_ID  = T1.ACCOUNT_ID
  WHERE
    LOCATION_CITY = 'New York' 
    AND LOCATION_NUM LIKE 'NY1%' 
    AND ACCOUNT_NUM IN ('40001','40002','40003')
)
SET 
   LOCATION_TYPE = 'TYPE 1'
;
```

When running it I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key preserved table
```

Answer (score 2):

When you try an update through join, like you are, two conditions must be true:

- The lookup key in the lookup table (you have two tables, so two lookup keys, `location_id` in `tblcenter` and `account_id` in `tblaccount`) must not have duplicates; it must be "unique" (in the sense of "no duplicate values"). This is an obvious logical requirement; if it is not met, the problem of updating, based on an ambiguous lookup, is nonsense.
- Oracle needs to know **beforehand**, at parse time, that the uniqueness will hold. That is, the tables must have unique constraints and/or unique indexes on those columns. This is not a logical requirement, but rather an Oracle implementation requirement. The error message is telling you that this second condition is not met, for at least one of the two lookup tables (possibly for both).

How to solve this? You have a few options:

- Simplest: create UNIQUE constraints (or PRIMARY KEY constraints) on those columns in those tables. Very likely they are *meant* to be PK's in the first place, but they aren't. Note here - "primary key" or "unique" constraints *maintained in the application* - as I am told PeopleSoft does, for example - **do not help**.
- You could update through a MERGE statement. The syntax will be quite similar. The difference is that MERGE waits until it sees all the data, and complains only if it **in fact** finds duplicates in the actual data where duplicates shouldn't be found.
- Slightly less efficient, but an obvious workaround: rewrite the statement as

  update tblsales
  set    location_type = 'TYPE 1'
  where  ( ..... )

...and only now I realized I don't really goes in the WHERE clause. It would help if you would say (in the UPDATE statement itself!) which columns come from which tables. I will guess that LOCATION_NUM is from the SALES table? Then the WHERE clause should be something like

```
where location_num like 'NY1%'
  and location_num in (select location_num from the three-way join)
```

(assuming that was the meaning of your original UPDATE statement).